# Enum evaluates to null in android studio debugger

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, enums

I am running into an odd issue with enums in my Android project.  I have done a lot of searching and haven't came up with anything similar to what I am seeing.  Here is the problem:  I created a new android project and I noticed my app crashed on an enum.  On investigation it seems everywhere I use an enum it evaluates to null in the debugger.  I did a simple example to demonstrate what I am seeing:

```
public class foo
{
    public enum fdsa {
        one,
        two,
        three
    }

   public foo() {
        fdsa state;
        state = fdsa.two;

        switch (state) {
            case one:
                Toast.makeText(mAsdfView.getContext(), "one called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case two:
                Toast.makeText(mAsdfView.getContext(), "two called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

        }
```

[image]

When I put a breakpoint on case two and hover the cursor over the enum, it shows as null.  It does this for every enum I use in the project.

I am at a loss for how to proceed.  Enums worked just fine in the project I used as the base for this one.   I am thinking it may be a setting off or something?  I have the debugger at my disposal, but I don't know enough to make headway using it.  Hoping someone has any advice or tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hovering over the the case statement, not the enum variable itself (which is `state`).  It's not a variable, so I'm not sure why the debugger is showing *anything* here - it looks like a bug - but it should show the correct value if you inspect `state` instead of `two`.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing that out to me.  My app was crashing and when I went into the debugger it was showing enum as null which made me think that was the problem.  After your comment I looked at it from a different angle and figured out the problem.